# I have a really odd bug in my function and can't figure it out

Tags: javascript

I am building an API for some video editing software in JXA - JavaScript for Automation, for Mac OS X. One of the most important "types" the API implements is the TimeFrame type. In short it looks like this: `hh:mm:ss:ff`

This is my function which produces the type:

```
function TimeFrame(val){
    if(typeof val == "string"){
        regex = /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/
        arr = regex.exec(val)
        h = parseInt(arr[1])
        m = parseInt(arr[2])
        s = parseInt(arr[3])
        f = parseInt(arr[4])
        this.frames = f + s*30 + m*60*30 + h*60*60*30
    } else {
        this.frames = Math.round(val)|0
    }

    this.toString = function(){
        t = this.frames
        h = parseInt(t/30/60/60)
        m = parseInt(t/30/60%60)
        s = parseInt(t/30%60)
        f = t%30

        //Pad puts "0" infront of single digit values.
        function pad(obj) {
          return obj.toString().length > 1 ? obj : "0" + obj
        }

        return pad(h) + ":" + pad(m) + ":" + pad(s) + ":" + pad(f)
    }
    this.valueOf = function(){
        return this.frames
    }
}
```

The function would be used as follows

```
var ti = new TimeFrame("00:01:32:10") //1 minute 32 seconds and 10 frames
var tf = new TimeFrame("00:01:32:12") //1 minute 32 seconds and 12 frames
var td = new TimeFrame(tf-ti)
td.toString() // returns 00:00:00:02, or 2 frames.
```

This is just an example of how to find the difference between 2 example intervals. However my problem is occurring when not initialising the function in the default manner:

```
var t = new TimeFrame(30)
t.toString() //returns "00:00:01:00" as expected
var t = new TimeFrame()
t.toString() //returns "00:00:00:00" as expected
t.frames = 30
t.toString() //returns "0" ?!? It should return "00:00:01:00" as above...
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: I have copied this exactly, minus adding `var` to the beginning of variable declarations and i get the expected results, haven't been able to produce what you are seeing. http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/EZdVNR?editors=1011

Comment: Your code is correct! You just choosed the worst example (`var t = ...` then `var t = ...`). Just change `t` to `t2` or something and you'll see that it work flawlessly!

Comment: And just as an advice: **USE THE DAMN SEMICOLONS ;**. You're making an API for guard sake!

Comment: Curious, why are semicolons important? The only reason i can think of is compression?